# Cookie and Session id issue when protocol switches from https to http

Tags: apache, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, cookies

I have an ecommerce site which is mix of https and http  urls.
I have two environments configured with Cisco ace load balancer, Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 7.0.339. There is an issue happening in one environment but not in other. In both of these environments, redirects are at the Apache level and  SSL configurations are in load balancer. Session is maintained using cookies.

First env – When site URL is accessed with https like `https: //xyz.com`, it creates a non-secure cookie in the browser and session id gets created. This cookie is getting created with this name (WWW.XYZ.COM-173.19.1.23-443-COOKIE). First issue, How come cookie gets created with 443 protocol because in firebug it shows as non-secure cookie.

Now, User browse the site and add the items to cart (until now everything happens in https since site initially accessed with https). When he clicks on cart link, URL gets switched from https to http and he is able to see the products in his cart. Session id remain change, same cookie is being used. This is very strange, because I read on Google, session id should change whenever protocol changes from https to http. Also, how come same cookie is used on both the protocols?

Other Env – Performed same steps, same cookie gets created (WWW.XYZ.COM-173.19.1.23-443-COOKIE). When URL switches from https to http, session id changes and a different cookie on port 80 (WWW.XYZ.COM-173.19.1.23-80-COOKIE )  with this name is returned. Because of this no products are shown on my cart page.

Just to add, cookie secure flag is not set as true anywhere in codebase, nor in Apache not in Tomcat. Why the cookie gets created with 443, I don’t know.

Is anything happening at load balancer level? This issue works fine on both the env, when site is initially accessed using http.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably change to https when login screen comes and dont return to http after login. So, keep all data in secure cookie and then it wouldn't be the problem. Your cart details will be in secure one.

As to your concern about secure flag, it should be set by the application sever when sending the cookie. The browsers which support the secure flag will only send cookies with the secure flag when the request is going to a HTTPS page. And if you are setting the secure flag, the browser will prevent the transmission of a cookie over an unencrypted channel. How to set the flag?

Your question doesnt contain what you use but for your information:

Servlet 3.0 (Java EE 6): Methods setSecure and isSecure can be used to set and check for secure value in cookies. In web.xml, you cal also set in this way:

```
<session-config>
<cookie-config>
<secure>true</secure>
</cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

In Tomcat, you use:

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; secure");
```

In ASP.NET,

```
Set the following in Web.config: <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

For some objects that have a requireSSL property, like the forms Authentication Cookie, set the requireSSL="true" flag in the web.config for that specific element.

If you use scripting languages like PHP, you can have a look at here how to send the secure flag param:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
```

Although you ought use secure-flagged cookie, but you may also consider using database session if you really care about the contents of cart. The performance is quite comparable, if you know how default session works keeping files and reading/writing them.

Comment: Well, we are not setting the secure flag=true anywhere in the system. Even after that how come this issue is happening ? How come cookie gets created with 443 port and jsession id not changing in first env but changing in other.
And this whole issue comes when site is just accessed using https://, login is not required. Also, can you please let me know what is the use of this ?"For some objects that have a requireSSL property, like the forms Authentication Cookie, set the requireSSL="true" flag in the web.config for that specific element."

Comment: Also, i guess this is for ASP.net "For some objects that have a requireSSL property, like the forms Authentication Cookie, set the requireSSL="true" flag in the web.config for that specific element."

Comment: I think if you don't set secure flag, you leave it to the browser to decide as you tell that "I dont care if you keep it secure or not". 

But it may consider other data/headers etc. available to it to make its own decision if you leave it to it. 

Port 443 is used for SSL connections - no matter you set secure flag or not, however you have the Secure property as false in this case. If you want to use port 443 in both your environments, specify Secure = true specifically, then it should be the same result in both your environments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Over https, cookie gets created with 443 port in both the env. SSL is configured in both the envs with same configurations. And secure flag is not set true in both the env, then why session id not changing in first env when it switches the protocol from https to http. But changes in second env.

Comment: Both using the same type of ssl certificate? Or one is self-signed? How are you sure the both env are same? Cloned it?
The logic says there must be something different between the two env.

Comment: ssl certificate same on both, no one is self signed. I have checked  context.xml, server.xml, httpd.conf, web.xml. They are same. I could not check the cisco load balancer config.  In both of these environments, redirects are at the apache level and SSL configurations are in load balancer. Can there be something in load balancer which is actually causing this issue.

Comment: Hard to say, to be honest. Your code is same in both? Session id may change if you call to start a new session on the new pae with different protocol. Have you cleared all cookies and caches from browser to try? Not sure, but it can update an existing one instead of recreating in case when different port one already exists there.

Comment: code is same.i have cleared all cookies and cache. Since nothing is there at the app level, What i want to understand is, if load balancer or SSL can be configured in a way is, that it do not create the new session id and keeps the same cookies when protocol switches.

Comment: Try setting secure flag to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding on your problem, the `http` is a default for website while the `https` can be enabled using web hosting server. There is an option there that you need to enabled its https access.

Try using also redirection codes if you need to switch `http` to `https` or vice versa. But if your website is dealing with Ecommerce with payment gateway I suggest to use `https` for better security of your website.